# creative ways of inputting date and time

Tags: user-interface

i am working on a small experimental app where part of the form will be users entering date and time.

Apart from the calendars ...are there any creative ways of inputting date and time that you have come across?

maybe have a text field with analog clock on top. when data is inputted in text fields and tabbed out the analog clock would show the time change.

Comment: is this web only? or any application/device?

Comment: I posed the question from web only point of view

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the [timpickr plugin for jQuery UI](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) has a novel approach to inputting time data.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) (jquery plugin) style of smart text box.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Outlook reminder window has a "remind me" field in which you can enter relative times in English free text, such as "1 day before" or "30 minutes from now".

For some things, that's more natural than having to do the math in your head and enter an absolute time or date.

Answer (score 0):

How about left click=set long arm - right click=set short arm - shift-click=second hand? :)

Answer (score 0):

How about letting the user move the hands of a clock.